# WMA conversion for playitslowly

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to transcribe some audio files. The original format is .WMA. 
I've tried using both:

```
ffmpeg -i some.WMA some.wav
```

and

```
pacpl -to wav some.WMA some.wav
```

as well as exporting with Audacity to mp3.

I've updated to the newest ffmpeg. The problem (despite the error message) doesn't seem to be the conversion.

Namely,

```
file some.wav
```

shows

```
some.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

and I still get the same resulting error message when trying to play some.wav (.mp3) with playitslowly:

```
** (app.py:31502): WARNING **: cannot set NULL uri
** Message: don't know how to handle audio/x-wma, wmaversion=(int)2, bitrate=(int)128016, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2, block_align=(int)5945, codec_data=(buffer)009000000f0039170000
```

(How) can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than monkey around with your distro's version of `ffmpeg` I'd suggest just getting the statically built version available on the FFmpeg's project page.

- [FFmpeg Download](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- [Static FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/)

They offer many pre-built versions for different architectures. Once you download and unpack it you can run it like so:

```
$ ./ffmpeg -i some.WMA some.wav
```

Comment: I updated to the newest ffmpeg. The problem doesn't seem to be the actual conversion. [I added comments above.] It seems to be some mystery with playitslowly. (Which I used in the past with no issues.)